# How to add a package to a new Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, pygal

I have installed the `pygal` package through the following command line:

```
conda install -c akode pygal
```

However, when I search this package in the Anaconda, I can only find this package in the base (root) environment. When I try to search this `pygal` package in my newly created environment, nothing can I find.

Why does this happen? and is there any solution to this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That's the point of environments. You need to activate the actual environment first and conda install _within_ it. This is entirely covered by the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are not in an environment and run conda install , it will install it in the base. If you activate your environment then install the package using conda install, it will apply to your environment.

```
source activate data_visualization_coursera
conda install -c akode pygal
```

Or you can install a specific package to an environment using this command

```
conda install -n <environment_name> <package_name>
```

You can find all of the documentation here https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html